# UITableView add more cells with Click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I added UIButton in the last cell of UITableView, and I want to show more cells with click..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    rowCount = 15;
    dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"the value of row is: %d", i +1];
        [dataArray addObject:value];
    }

}
```

...

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return rowCount;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *idintify = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.myTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:idintify];

    [cell.textLabel setText:dataArray[indexPath.row]];

    if (indexPath.row == rowCount -1) {
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.myTable.frame.size.width, 44)];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(cellButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTitle:@"Show more..." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell addSubview:button];

    }


    return cell;
}
```

...

```
- (void)cellButtonClicked
{
    if (rowCount +10 >= dataArray.count) {
        rowCount = dataArray.count;

    } else {
        rowCount += 10;
    }
    [self.myTable reloadData];
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)rowCount);
}
```

At beginning its work properly, But when I scrolled the table the cell did not changed!

[image]

I want to show the button at last cell

Comment: If I may you should avoid putting such a button and instead start loading more when the user scroll to the end of the list

Comment: @wissam iOS I dont see any problem with your code. Can you provide the Code of your .m Class/ir  a link for the .m class, so that We can check if there's any other mistake

Comment: @wissam iOS suggestion: If u r using a Storyboard and taking prototype buttons, try taking two buttons one for displaying data and other for the Button only.

Comment: @Jeev it is a cell reuse problem nothing else.

Comment: @sumit Garg I believe taking two other than 1 button in storyboard will help. the table is creating prob/ or unable to refresh itself for the Last button. 2 button concept will take care of that

Comment: @Jeev another better option is you used two prototype cells instead of one. One for text and another for button.

Comment: @SumitGarg Typo: I was mentioning 2 cells, Mistakely I wrote 2 buttons; correcting it now.

Comment: One another Crack In-spite of taking an another Cell: I would have colored the Background of my last cell and taking  its cell.textlabel.textAlignment center and then in the did Select delegate I will check if the User has Clicked the Last row or not; Clicking the last row, I will reload data as per Requirement

Comment: @Jeev Ok i think both of us mentioning the same thing.

Comment: Cell prototypes are exactly for this purpose. Create one for the data, and one for the button cell. On the last index, return the button cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cells in a table view are reused when the user scrolls. When you add a button to an instance of your cell prototype and don't remove it, the button remains, even if the cell is used at another index later. This results in what you have on your screenshots.

You should create two cell prototypes in the interface builder and your cellForRow:atIndexPath: should look something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return cell with data

    if (indexPath.row < dataArray.count) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.myTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell_prototype_1"];
        [cell.textLabel setText:dataArray[indexPath.row]];
        return cell;
    }     

    // If it's the last index, return cell with button

    else {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.myTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell_prototype_2"];
        return cell;
    }

    // This won't get called

    return [UITableViewCell new];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That will be better if you use two different cells otherwise replace the code in your cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if (indexPath.row == rowCount -1){}
```

with

```
if ( (indexPath.row-15)%10 == 0 ){}
```

and Put

```
[cell.textLabel setText:dataArray[indexPath.row]];
```

in the else part.

and place code just below  UITableViewCell *cell....

```
for(UIView *view in cell.view.subviews){
   if([view isKindOfClass: [UIButton class]]){
[view removeFromSuperView];
   }
}
```

Comment: for(UIView *view in cell.view.subviews){ is also Good, But again the for loop and if have to run again and again

Comment: @Jeev I know this is not a good approach but I have already define used two prototype cell for better implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to refresh visible cells, doing:

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] 
             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Also better way to do it would be that you have 2 prototype cells, one for data, one with button. let's sey you give the second one identifier "buttonCell", than you just do this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *idintify = (indexPath.row < rowCount -) ? @"Cell" : @"buttonCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.myTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:idintify];

    if (cell == nil) //initialize 

    if (indexPath.row < rowCount -1) {
        [cell.textLabel setText:dataArray[indexPath.row]];

    }

    return cell;
}
```

and in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you increase `rowCount` and reload data if `indexPath.row == rowCount - 1`

Comment: reloadRowsAtIndexPaths wont do a difference. I always recommend taking two different Cell in the Prototype. Declaring your own Uicompoenets in Cell for INdexpath; TableView creates resue Problem